# Percentage calculation based on entity fields data in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

If the entity has 10 fields and 5 fields has data and 5 fields has no data in database record, then the percentage of that entity record has 50%.

How can we calculate using Spring data jpa or any existing libraries in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Reflection in a transient field of the entity class.

```
@Transient
public float getPercentDone() {
  var propDesc = BeanUtilsBean2.getInstance().getPropertyUtils().getPropertyDescriptors(this);
  var allProps = Arrays.stream(propDesc).filter(prop -> !"percentDone".equals(prop.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  var countNotNull = allProps.stream().filter(prop -> {
    try {
      return BeanUtilsBean2.getInstance().getProperty(this, prop.getName()) != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }).count();

  return (countNotNull * 100.0f) / allProps.size();
}
```

I used [BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) from Apache Commons for this, but if you can't use that, you can do the same with out-of-the-box reflection (it is just longer).

### Skipping Fields

To skip fields like ids and join fields, you can create a list. And replace the filter with one that checks the list of skipped properties. If you put this in a `@MappedSuperclass` the entity children only need to override the list.

**Note**: `percentDone` and `skippedProperties` must both be skipped fields themselves.

```
List<String> skippedProperties = List.of("percentDone", "skippedProperties", "id", "user");
...
@Transient
public float getPercentDone() {
  var propDesc = BeanUtilsBean2.getInstance().getPropertyUtils().getPropertyDescriptors(this);
  var allProps = Arrays.stream(propDesc)
        .filter (prop -> !skippedProperties.contains(prop.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  var countNotNull = allProps.stream().filter(prop -> {
    try {
      return BeanUtilsBean2.getInstance().getProperty(this, prop.getName()) != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }).count();

  return (countNotNull * 100.0f) / (allProps.size() - skippedProperties.size());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.     In my question, missed one scenario.                                                                   
Scenario: I have total 6 fields, I need to check only 3 fields for percentage calculation and remaing 3 fields need to skip  ( Field types are primary key field and relation ship key fields)
public class Employee {
    private Long id;  // skip 
    private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
    private MailingAddressDto address;  // skip 
    private UploadFileDto profileImage;  // skip 
    private String websiteUrl;
 }.

Comment: To skip a field, you would add an additional filter clause to the stream processor. `allProps.stream().filter(p -> !p.getName().equals("id").prop(prop -> ...`

Comment: Thank you for the response. To skip id field, I will pass additional filter clause to the stream, for other fields like address and profileImage, is there any other way to check instead of passing statically in filter clause. I have different data types(user, company etc)  in remaining entities and I would like to write one logic to reuse for all the entities. Could you please suggest me any other idea if you have.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved lot of time to me.

Comment: Can we do same thing at SQL database level

Comment: If you mean calculating the percentage of columns in the db that are non-null, then yes, but it isn't going to be nearly as dynamic as the JPA solution.
(BTW, since the answer worked, would you mind upvoting it?)

Comment: I tried, but I don't have option to do that due to reputation, it's helped using JPA.

Comment: If you have any solution using SQL to get the same way please provide me that.